# GWT - Compilation error: No source code is available for type

Tags: java, maven, gwt, compiler-errors, gwt2

I am building GWT application by Maven.

When compiling get the following message:

```
Validating newly compiled units
```

At first there is this warning:

```
[WARNING] Don't declare gwt-dev as a project dependency. This may introduce complex dependency conflicts
```

Then there is this error:

```
[ERROR] Line 19: No source code is available for type org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

Despite this build does not fall and Dev mode works properly.
How can I get rid of these error messages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps a reason is in your module file. You should to identify packages that is to be compiled. This is configured in `.gwt.xml` module.

```
<source path="packagename">
```

And GWT compiler will compile packages **gwtxmlmodulepath.packagename**.

[See more](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects#DevGuideModuleXml)

Answer (score 8):

The error means that some of the client code (to be compiled as javascript) contains a reference to the StringUtils class from Apache Commons. This is not allowed because this library contains code that is not GWT-client compatible.